# Terminal says there is no file

Tags: terminal, macos-sierra

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4jvQ.png)

PLEASE HELP! I can't seem to run my file. I've compiled it so it should run shouldn't it?

It also happens to my other files and I can't seem to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so a quick point of notice:

- It is usually appreciated if you post your code directly in your question and use the `code markup` for that. It makes it easier to answer your question and prevents the image from turning into a dead-link at one point in time.

Then, regarding your code: it seems your Topic3ex1.c still has some errors, it always helps to fix them first. Maybe the errors are preventing Topic3ex1 (which I believe you have selected as the output file with the -o option? I am not familiar with gcc's syntax.) from being formed. Check if the file exist first by executing `ls -a` from the command line.

If you get a message saying "No such file or directory" while it is indeed there, this is usually caused by a lack of user rights. Try executing `chmod u+x Topic3ex1.c` and then run your command again. This will give your current user the right to execute the file (read up on chmod if you do not know it already, you will need it often).

Final question: is Topic3ex1 supposed to be a file or a folder? For if it is a file, then executing it like `./Topic3ex1` will only work if it is a shellscript (in that case, best rename your file to Topic3ex1.sh, its best to always mention the extension of the file). If it is a folder the `./` command won't do anything and the `cd Topic3ex1` (cq. change directory-)command you where experiencing with will activate it as your working directory. If it is a file however, then the change directory command will, of course, be useless.